# javascript hexadecimal color convert into rgb function

Tags: javascript, function, hex, rgb

I am new in Javascript. I want to create a function which will take a hexadecimal color code and it will convert it to rgb(xx,xx,xx).
My code is found below

```
function my(a){
var first = a[1] + a[2];
var second = a[3] + [4];
var third = a[5] + a[6];
var res = [first,second,third];
for(var i = 0; i <res.length; i++){
res[i] = parseInt(res[i],16);
}
return res;
}
```

First and third array element is converting correctly except second array element. I don't why, can anyone tell me why?

Comment: indexes in javascript arrays start with 0, not 1

Comment: @manonthemat But isn't the hex started with `#`? So element at index 0 isn't a number.

Comment: So `a` is a string in the form of `#ccdd11` then? Well, that makes sense then.

Comment: yes hex number start with # so i started from 1. yes i treated "a" as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a typo in assigning `second`. You had `a[3] + [4]`, when it should be `a[3] + a[4]`.

```
function my(a) {
    var first = a[1] + a[2];
    var second = a[3] + a[4];
    var third = a[5] + a[6];
    var res = [first,second,third];
    for(var i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
        res[i] = parseInt(res[i],16);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your time